# fetch select option tag data by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am fetching select tag options value by Ajax (fetching from mysql )

but when i am submitting form , jquery is fetching wrong data

here is example for what i want to say

`<select>
<option value='1'> 100 </option>
</select>`

I want to fetch '1' but jquery fetching '100'

I am using this code for fetching data

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#form").submit(function()
{
var mydata=$("#select").val();
});
});
```

html code

```
<form method='post' id='form'>
<select id='select'>
<option value='1'>100</option>
<option value='2'>200</option>
</select>
</form>
```

note: i am fetching option tag values from mysql database using ajax

Comment: are you sure of this have you inspected the `option` tag after fetching it's `value` attribute's value from the data base

Comment: also can you post the code to show how are you altering the `option tag`'s value after fetching the data from data base

Comment: before fetching data from mysql my select tag code is this  <select id='select'></select>   after fetching data it is display <select id='select'><option value='1'>100</option><option value='2'>200</option></select>    i know we can't see  this code in source code but i am displaying that by alert();

Comment: i think problem is in some other part in your code because it's working here:- http://jsfiddle.net/8Ebuy/2/ .I have added a button to dynamically add the option tags like you are doing through ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var selected = 0;
$('#select').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':selected')) {
    selected = $(this).val();
  }
});
alert(selected);
```